# Macro to insert comments on keywords in selected text in a Word doc?

Tags: vba, macros, ms-word

I'm new to VBA and would greatly appreciate some help on a problem.

I have long Word documents where I need to apply standard comments to the same set of keywords, but only in selected sections of the document. The following macro worked to find a keyword and apply a comment (from question here https://superuser.com/questions/547710/macro-to-insert-comment-bubbles-in-microsoft-word):

```
Sub label_items()
'
' label_items Macro
'
'
Do While Selection.Find.Execute("keyword1") = True
    ActiveDocument.Comments.Add range:=Selection.range, Text:="comment for keyword 1"
Loop

End Sub
```

The two modifications are:

1) only apply the comments to user selected text, not the whole document. I tried a "With Selection.Range.Find" approach but I don't think comments can be added this way (??)

2) repeat this for 20+ keywords in the selected text. The keywords aren't totally standard and have names like P_1HAI10, P_1HAI20, P_2HAI60, P_HFS10, etc.

EDIT: I have tried to combine code from similar questions (  [Word VBA: finding a set of words and inserting predefined comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37881513/word-vba-finding-a-set-of-words-and-inserting-predefined-comments?rq=1) and [Word macro, storing the current selection (VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000582/word-macro-storing-the-current-selection-vba)) but my current attempt (below) only runs for the first keyword and comment and runs over the entire document, not just the text I have highlighted/selected.

```
Sub label_items()
'
' label_items Macro
'
Dim selbkup As range
Set selbkup = ActiveDocument.range(Selection.range.Start, Selection.range.End)

Set range = selbkup

Do While range.Find.Execute("keyword 1") = True
    ActiveDocument.Comments.Add range, "comment for keyword 1"
Loop

Set range = selbkup

Do While range.Find.Execute("keyword 2") = True
    ActiveDocument.Comments.Add range, "comment for keyword 2"
Loop

'I would repeat this process for all of my keywords

End Sub
```

I've combed through previous questions and the Office Dev Center and am stuck. Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of adding a loop and a means of `Finding` the next keyword you're looking for. There are a few suggestions in the code example below, so please adjust it as necessary to fit your requirements.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub label_items()
    Dim myDoc As Document
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Set myDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set targetRange = Selection.Range

    '--- drop a bookmark to return the cursor to it's original location
    Const RETURN_BM = "OrigCursorLoc"
    myDoc.Bookmarks.Add Name:=RETURN_BM, Range:=Selection.Range

    '--- if nothing is selected, then search the whole document
    If Selection.Start = Selection.End Then
        Selection.Start = 0
        targetRange.Start = 0
        targetRange.End = myDoc.Range.End
    End If

    '--- build list of keywords to search
    Dim keywords() As String
    keywords = Split("SMS,HTTP,SMTP", ",", , vbTextCompare)

    '--- search for all keywords within the user selected range
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(keywords)
        '--- set the cursor back to the beginning of the
        '    originally selected range
        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=RETURN_BM
        Do
            With Selection.Find
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindStop
                .Text = keywords(i)
                .Execute

                If .Found Then
                    If (Selection.Start < targetRange.End) Then
                        Selection.Comments.Add Selection.Range, _
                                               Text:="Found the " & keywords(i) & " keyword"
                    Else
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
            End With
        Loop
    Next i

    '--- set the cursor back to the beginning of the
    '    originally selected range
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=RETURN_BM

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, PeterT! This worked perfectly. I didn't use the "if nothing selected" piece and tweaked how the comment text was generated, but otherwise this did the job exactly. Thanks very much!